# Create a custom image size (Can't register my size)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I need to resize images. I'm creating my own plugin (not theme).
Here's what I use:

```
function myplugintest_custom_image_size_500_x_500() {
    add_image_size( 'myplugintest-size-500-500', 500, 500,0 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'myplugintest_custom_image_size_500_x_500' );
```

Then I need to get a link to the image to display in my custom block (in myplugintest.php).

```
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($product->get_image_id(), 'myplugintest-size-500-500', false);
```

But I get the original image with the scaled suffix.

This works if I use already registered sizes, for example:

```
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($product->get_image_id(), 'woocommerce_single', false);
```

What could be the problem and how do I register my size?

Upd 1:

If you dive deeper `wp_get_attachment_image_url` into the function, you can find `wp_get_attachment_metadata`, which returns `$meta`. In `$meta` there is an array `sizes` which contains all registered sizes, but my size is not there.

Comment: Use `after_setup_theme` and not `init`

Comment: @HowardE It did not help. Do I need to reinstall the theme or plugin?